# How to input on a running process in a terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to make a script in Linux, that starts a program (in the terminal), and then write what I want in the context of the already running program.
For example, I have myScript.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I want to open pgcli"
pgcli -h #ARGUMENTS#
....
```

When I run it from a terminal, this of course get stuck when the **pgcli** starts. And when I manually finish it, the following statements are executed.
What I'mt trying to do is: when **pgcli** starts and ask me for password, the script to write the password IN the context of the program (and then, another SQL statements).

Can this be done in a script? If so, how could I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your program reads from stdin,
if you have a file containing all the needed input like so:

```
password
sql query1
sql query2
```

then you can do something like:

```
cat input | pgcli
```

in your script. Or just do

```
echo "input" | pgcli
```